# PHP create arrays from array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

I have two tables, `content` and `theme`. There are several `theme` rows that should be obtained for each row in the `content` table. This I have done with PDO and a mySQL query involving a `LEFT JOIN`. The output array gives me one array per occurence of a theme file (below).

I want to reorganise the array so that I get one array per `contentID` with an array within that array containing each of the matching theme files.

The idea being that something like `$content=>'theme'['logo']` would grab the value for one of the matching theme files.

How would this be done.

```
array(
       array (
            contentID => 1, 
            title => 'test', 
            subtitle = 'a description', 
            themeID => 1,
            theme_file => 'navigation'
        )

        array (
            contentID => 1, 
            title => 'test', 
            subtitle = 'a description', 
            themeID => 2,
            theme_file => 'logo'
        )
)
```

As requested I have added additional code. There are in fact 3 tables I wish to nest inside each other but for the purpose of a helpful question to others I kept it at 2. This is the mySQL query if helpful:

```
SELECT * 
FROM content
LEFT JOIN content_theme ON content.contentID = content_theme.contentID
LEFT JOIN theme ON theme.themeID = content_theme.themeID
OR theme.default =1
LEFT JOIN theme_meta ON theme.themeID = theme_meta.themeID
WHERE content.contentID = 9
ORDER BY theme.default DESC
```

The intention therefore is to for each `content` row to nest all its matching `theme` rows, and for each of these `theme` rows to nest each of their matching `theme_meta` rows

Raw output from the database:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 
            [0] => 4
            [type] => page
            [1] => page
            [type_alts] => 
            [2] => 
            [url] => about
            [3] => about
            [title] => About
            [4] => About
            [subtitle] => 
            [5] => 
            [online] => 1
            [6] => 1
            [req] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [pos] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [parent] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [content_theme_ID] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [themeID] => 2
            [12] => 
            [13] => 2
            [theme_type] => general
            [14] => general
            [theme_file] => logo
            [15] => logo
            [theme_default] => 1
            [16] => 1
            [theme_title] => MD Group
            [17] => MD Group
            [18] => 2
            [field] => src
            [19] => src
            [value] => uploads/img/murphey-dines-group-logo.png
            [20] => uploads/img/murphey-dines-group-logo.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 
            [0] => 4
            [type] => page
            [1] => page
            [type_alts] => 
            [2] => 
            [url] => about
            [3] => about
            [title] => About
            [4] => About
            [subtitle] => 
            [5] => 
            [online] => 1
            [6] => 1
            [req] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [pos] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [parent] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [content_theme_ID] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [themeID] => 2
            [12] => 
            [13] => 2
            [theme_type] => general
            [14] => general
            [theme_file] => logo
            [15] => logo
            [theme_default] => 1
            [16] => 1
            [theme_title] => MD Group
            [17] => MD Group
            [18] => 2
            [field] => title
            [19] => title
            [value] => murphey dines Group
            [20] => murphey dines Group
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [contentID] => 
            [0] => 4
            [type] => page
            [1] => page
            [type_alts] => 
            [2] => 
            [url] => about
            [3] => about
            [title] => About
            [4] => About
            [subtitle] => 
            [5] => 
            [online] => 1
            [6] => 1
            [req] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [pos] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [parent] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [content_theme_ID] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [themeID] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 7
            [theme_type] => general
            [14] => general
            [theme_file] => navigation
            [15] => navigation
            [theme_default] => 1
            [16] => 1
            [theme_title] => Main Navigation
            [17] => Main Navigation
            [18] => 
            [field] => 
            [19] => 
            [value] => 
            [20] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: PHP is pretty good at making nested arrays the way you described.  But you probably may need to share more code to get help with what you're asking.

Comment: @JoeT additional code added.

Comment: Could you show an example result set from your query?  I think you basically want to loop over all the ContentIDs, then within that loop run your query, get the results as an associative array and loop over that assigning $content[$ContentID][$theme] equal to each row.

Comment: @JoeT that is exactly what I want to do. I'll add the array output.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the arrays like this i suppose.

```
$aContent = array();
foreach($aRows AS $aRow){
    $aContent[$aRow['contentID']][] = array(
        'theme' => array(
            'themeID' => $aRow['themeID'],
            'themeType' => $aRow['theme_type'],
            'themeTitle' => $aRow['theme_title']
        ),
        'type' => 'page',
    );
}
```